# WinDivert filter, to block all TCP connections, except an IP

Tags: tcp, wfp

I'm trying to write a filter to use with [WinDivert](https://github.com/basil00/Divert), to block all TCP connections, except for an IP.

When I write

```
outbound && ip && (tcp.DstPort == 80 || tcp.DstPort == 443) && tcp.PayloadLength> 0
```

it blocks all connections. But when I write

```
outbound && ip && 
(tcp.DstPort == 80 || tcp.DstPort == 443) && 
tcp.PayloadLength> 0 && ip.src! = 91.198.174.192
```

everything is still blocked and the IP address is not open.

I think my filter is not correct, and any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the property `ip.src` is not exists, but `ip.SrcAddr` (case sensitive!).

but if the filter id addressed to outbound, the may mean the destination address (`ip.DstAddr`), so you need type:

```
outbound && ip.DstAddr != x.x.x.x
```

TIP: you can check the expression using the "netfilter.exe" tool, download from [here](https://reqrypt.org/download/WinDivert-1.4.3-A.zip) (extract the folder, and open the command line in the `x86_64` or `x86` folder, and run flowed by a string argument that represent the filter expression)

Comment: Thank you.    Now another question, how can i allow all local trafic, and block distant network?